# android.util.GregorianCalendar: will c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1) rollback or forward?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-calendar, watchface

If the Calendar is on the last day of the month (say 31st of July) , will

```
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

set c to the start of the same month, July, or will it advance c to the next month, August?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation of the superclass [`java.util.Calendar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html), in the section named "*Field Manipulation*" (emphasis mine):

> `add(f, delta)` adds `delta` to field `f`. This is equivalent to calling `set(f, get(f) + delta)` with two adjustments:
>
> *Add rule 1*. The value of field `f` after the call minus the value of field `f` before the call is `delta`, modulo any overflow that has occurred in field `f`. **Overflow** occurs when a field value exceeds its range and, as a result, the **next larger field is incremented** or decremented and the field value is adjusted back into its range.

So `add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)` will change 31st of July to **1st of August**.

In contrast, the documentation continues:

> `roll(f, delta)` adds `delta` to field `f` without changing larger fields. This is equivalent to calling `add(f, delta)` with the following adjustment:
>
> *Roll rule*. **Larger fields are unchanged** after the call. A larger field represents a larger unit of time. `DAY_OF_MONTH` is a larger field than `HOUR`.

So `roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)` will change 31st of July to **1st of July**.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps there is some advantage to java lacking a repl. I learned more from your response that I would have from testing. It's also good to know about the roll method.

Answer (score 0):

Months in Calendar object start from 0. so 1 means February. And you know february last day is 28 so output should be 2 March.

```
0 = January = Calendar.JANUARY
1 = february = Calendar.FEBRUARY
```

so

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

int year       = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month      = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); 
int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // Jan = 0, not 1
```